# MS Visual Studio 2012: build statically linked exe

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, static-linking

I'm using visual studio 2012 and C++ and I'm tying to build a fully static executable of my program. It uses OpenCV 2.4.6 and I wish to be able to run it on a machine without any OpenCV (or even the standard c++ library) installed. I tried to follow every guide on the argument but i couldn't get around it, so here I am.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Sorry, crystal ball out of order.

Comment: Give us more details, it's not possible to say what's wrong basing only on the information "it's not working".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont have 2.4.6 but should be exactly the same

- build opencv with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` off
- set `vs2012->project properties->c/c++->code generation->runtime library->multi-threaded(/MT)`
- set linker input to following

```
    opencv_core245.lib
    opencv_contrib245.lib
    opencv_features2d245.lib
    opencv_objdetect245.lib
    opencv_nonfree245.lib
    opencv_highgui245.lib
    opencv_flann245.lib
    opencv_imgproc245.lib
    opencv_video245.lib
    opencv_legacy245.lib
    opencv_gpu245.lib
    opencv_ml245.lib
    IlmImf.lib
    libjasper.lib
    libpng.lib
    libtiff.lib
    libjpeg.lib
    zlib.lib
    Vfw32.Lib
    comctl32.lib
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't turn off the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` flag thus setting the properties to multithread didn't work.